# Changes to .bst file have no effect

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I have been using the `natbib` package with the apalike bibliography style. However, I am not entirely happy with some details of this style, and wanted to try my hands on a customised version. Thus, I looked up the `apalike.bst` file, made a copy of it (`myapalike.bst`), and changed the preamble:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{myapalike}
```

The problem is that none of the changes that I make to `myapalike.bst` has any effect when I compile. I have tried numerous solutions (compiling multiple times, refreshing the FNDB, moving the `.bst` file to the folder in which my `.tex` file is), but nothing works. I really have no clue what's going on.

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXstudio on a Windows machine. The `apalike.bst` as well as its copy `myapalike.bst` are located in the `.\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\apalike` folder.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: perhaps a silly question, but did you rerun bibtex after changing the bibliography style, and then latex again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please do not change the system texmf tree, like adding own `.bst` files into `.\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\` or sub directories ...

In my opinion the best way to use a changed `.bst` file is to do the following:

1. Create a local texfm folder, for example `C:\localtexmf` (I hope, you have allready one?)
2. Create the following sub directories: `C:\localtexmf\bibtex\bst`
3. Copy your file `myapalike.bst` into the `bst` directory in your localtexmf 
   (`C:\localtexmf\bibtex\bst\myapalike.bst`)
4. Tell MiKTeX that there is a local TeXmf tree: open MiKTeX settings,  click on `Root`, Click `add` to give MiKTeX the path (c:\localtexmf`)  to your local texmf. Then click into the box to show the MiKTeX maintained directories.  Then you should see this:

[image]

5. Now tell MiKTeX that there are changes (new `.bst` file). open MiKTeX settings, click on `General`, `Refresh FNDB` **and** `Update Formats` (you missed this).

[image]

6. Repeat step 5 if you have changed the `.bst` file.

After this you can call your `myapalike.bst` file like `apalike.bst`.

After the steps above you have (as usual) first to run `pdflatex` (to create the `*aux` file), 
then `bibtex` (or `biber`) to prepare the bibliography,  and then **two** times `pdflatex` again to include the bibliography, toc etc and to get proper page numbers.

Comment: Running bibtex from the command line prior to running latex (as suggested by barbara beeton above) did the trick, but I think that your solution is more solid. However, I still need to run bibtex from the command line after Step 5 in order to make changes effective!